# Trigger Performance - 1 or 2 Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trigger

I have a question about triggers performance.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_test](
[ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
[DateYearID] [INT] NULL,
[DateQuarterID] [INT] NULL,
[Date1] [DATETIME] NULL,
[Date1YearID] [INT] NULL,
[Date1QuarterID] [INT] NULL)
```

Now I want to have trigger that must update DateYearID and DateQuarterID columns if I update Date column (or insert a new row) , and must update Date1YearID and Date1QuarterID columns if I update Date1 column (or insert a new row). What is better, have a single trigger like

```
IF UPDATE(DATE)
   UPDATE _test SET DateYearID = ... , DateQuarterID = ...
IF UPDATE (DATE1)
   UPDATE _test SET Date1YearID = ... , Date1QuarterID = ...
```

or have two different triggers, first of them updating DateYearID,DateQuarterID columns, and the second one updateing DateYear1ID,DateQuarter1ID columns.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: If the columns `DateYearID`, `DateQuartedID`, `Date1YearID` and `Date1QuartedID` are simply calculations on the `date` / `date1` columns, I think you don't need a trigger at all and they can treated as computed columns. This is not clear from your question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest a single trigger, with a single pass through inserted and/or the base table, and just updating all four values for any row that is affected. I have proven before that [avoiding updating columns in a row where other column values have changed is not worth the effort](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates), and that [updating the same row twice from two different triggers will be slower](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/03/t-sql-queries/one-trigger-or-many).

```
IF UPDATE(DATE) OR UPDATE(DATE1)
BEGIN
  UPDATE t 
    SET DateYearID   = ...,
        DateQuarterID  = ...,
        Date1YearID    = ...,
        Date1QuarterID = ...
  FROM dbo._test AS t
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i
  ON t.ID = i.ID;
END
```

(Also, just as an aside, note that `UPDATE()` tells you the column was referenced in an update statement, but it doesn't guarantee that the value has changed.)

And yes, I agree with [Gianluca's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102777/trigger-performance-1-or-2-triggers#comment186151_102777): depending on how these four columns are calculated, you may not need a trigger at all. You may not even need a computed column - simple calculations (like `DATEPART(YEAR,Date1)`) are often best done at query time and only when you need them. Storing redundant data is overrated - I/O and memory are much more important than CPU in almost all systems, even with today's SSD and PCIe flash drives...